# shell pipelines using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-3.x, unix, process

I would like to use command containing multiple pipes with subprocess.Popen. Here's my short script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import subprocess
import datetime
import shlex

todayyearnumber = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y'))

command = 'git log --grep "' + todayyearnumber + '.*commit" --oneline'
command2 = 'cut -d " " -f4'

argsplit=shlex.split(command)
argsplit2=shlex.split(command2)

process1=subprocess.Popen(argsplit, cwd=ebb_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

process2=subprocess.Popen(argsplit2, stdin=process1.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(process2.stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

However, Im receiving an error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./proces.py", line 35, in 
    process2=subprocess.Popen(argsplit2, stdin=process1.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'PIPE'

Could you lend me a hand where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `PIPE` is a constant defined as `subprocess.PIPE`.

The complete program would be like below, if I understand you correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import shlex

command = 'echo a b c'
command2 = "awk '{print $2}'"

argsplit=shlex.split(command)
argsplit2=shlex.split(command2)

ebb_path="/tmp/"
process1=subprocess.Popen(argsplit, cwd=ebb_path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_data, stderr_data = process1.communicate(timeout=1)

process2=subprocess.Popen(argsplit2, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_data2, _ = process2.communicate(input=stdout_data,
                                    timeout=1)

print(stdout_data2.decode('utf-8'))
```